# Why was Christ's birthday changed?

Tags: new-testament, christmas, belief, birth

I have always had issues with the Bible and thought about God but my life is in shambles and everyone keeps telling me to just believe. So I am coming to get help and understand. When looking into Christ, I have seen that his birthday was set for December 25th. But yet when reading the Bible it says that they follow the star of Bethlehem which this star is not present in the sky until June 26th.

Please I want to believe but I need solid proof that this isn't just something people hold onto and this stuff is real and not fake.

Comment: The Bible says neither what day Jesus was born on, nor what exactly the star was. Any dates people are suggesting are only theories at best. If you want to consider Dec 25 a fake date, then go ahead! The true date of Jesus's birth is not important to Christianity.

Comment: _Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor._

Comment: A lot of Christians say a lot of things which are not stated in the Bible.  Sometimes these things are reasonably deduced and sometimes they are utterly baseless.  Your best bet is to read the Scriptures for yourself, all the while asking God to reveal His truth to you.

Comment: What Bible are you reading that said there was such a thing as the "Star of Bethlehem" and that  it was not present until June 26th?

Answer (score 3):

> I have always had issues with the bible

Of course you have! Humans are *by nature* sinful. It is in our very nature to run away from God and to do anything we possibly can to deny His existence. Scripture tells us that God a) made us, b) is perfect, and c) demands the same perfection from us. We know we aren't perfect, so the thought that someone has authority to judge us is... not pleasant, and many, many people will go to extreme lengths to hide from that reality. Those lengths include making up false history to explain what they see (life, the universe, everything ) while excluding God from the picture.

> When looking into Christ I have seen that his birthday was set on December 25th.

The key phrase there is "was set". At some point, the church decided that's when they would observe Christ's birthday... but scripture does not tell us the exact day. Now, on the one hand, modern Israel doesn't get a lot of snow; but on the other hand, the Flood triggered an ice age and might have been colder 2000 years ago. Thus, while not entirely conclusive, reading that shepherds were "out in the field, keeping watch over their flock by night" (Luke 2:8) when "unto [them] is born this day [...] a Savior, who is Christ the Lord" (Luke 2:11) might suggest the actual birth happened in summer. (In context, the angels were speaking to the shepherds, but Christ came for *everyone*.)

> But yet when reading the bible it says that they follow the star of Bethlehem which this star is not present in the sky until June 26th.

Citation needed? In any case, there is no problem here for several reasons. First, the star may not have appeared on the exact day of Christ's birth, and in particular, it is widely suspected that the visitation by the magi may have happened as late as a few *years* after Christ's birth. Remember, in those days, travel would have taken some time, implying that the star was present for weeks, or even months or years. Regardless, I'm not aware of Scripture stating when the star appeared (citation requested?), and even if it did, as shown above, we don't know the actual date of Christ's birth anyway for that to indicate a contradiction, even if we *do* assume the star appeared on the same day.

> I want to believe but I need solid proof that this isn't just something people hold onto and this stuff is real and not fake.

First, have a look at every other religion. You'll quickly see that they have one thing in common; what do *we* have to do to obtain salvation/enlightenment/nirvana/etc.? Now look at Christianity's answer to that question: **nothing**. In fact, we **can't** do anything to save ourselves, but "while we were still sinners, Christ died for us" (Romans 5:8). **God** does *all* the work. That, right there, is strongly suggestive; humans have a strong propensity to craft their own religions according to a particular form, and Christianity doesn't fit the mold... because the Christian religion doesn't come from humans, it comes from God, because it is true.

What else? Well, you're here. God-deniers struggle mightily to explain how that's possible, and their stories change all the time. Those stories also rely on seriously problematic assumptions, especially with respect to the age of Earth and the Universe (ages which, again, keep changing).

What evidence do we have that God exists? Start here:

> **Genesis 1:1**
>
> In the beginning, **God** created the heavens and the earth.

Unlike the vain stories told by non-believers, Christians have believed for over 2000 years that Earth was Created circa 4000-4500 BC. Jews have believed the same since the very day of Creation. Scripture does not change.

Non-believers will tell you that radiometric "dating" "*proves*" this is wrong, but their results are full of inconsistencies and contradict archaeology and recorded history. Those same results fail to explain any manner of phenomena from geology and astronomy that are consistent with "recent" Creation and a global Flood (as attested by nearly every culture on Earth). Nor can they explain why life exists, why it's tremendously diverse, or why life is full of beauty and mathematical elegance. They insist life must be "a near certainty" (because they can't face the fact that life is actually statistically impossible), but can't explain why it's only found here. Nor can they explain amazing coincidences such as the earth-moon-sun relation being just right to produce eclipses.

Some otherwise-Christians have, unfortunately, given in to pressure to "compromise" on these truths, but many others have not, and many organizations exist that can help you see the truth that the proof of God's existence is everywhere.

I would commend you, first, to find a local congregation that affirms God's Word, but I recognize that can be difficult. There are also internet resources you may find helpful:

- [Answers in Genesis](https://answersingenesis.org/) (Possibly the premiere organization, at least in the USA, for upholding the historicity of Genesis)
- [Christian Apologetics and Research Ministry](https://carm.org/) (A good site for discussing all manner of theology, not just science as it relates to Creation)
- [Creation Ministries International](https://creation.com/)
- [The Discovery Institute](https://www.discovery.org/) (DI doesn't uphold recent Creation, but is a great resource for putting "evolution" in its proper scope. Note that adaptation is definitely genuine; Common Descent, or the idea that humans had non-human ancestors, is utterly false.)
- [Got Questions](https://www.gotquestions.org/) (Another resource for Scriptural answers to theological and philosophical questions. Be aware that they have a strong Protestant bias and many Christians don't agree with them fully.)
- [The Institute for Creation Research](https://icr.org) (seems to be having issues with their SSL certificate as of writing; hopefully they'll be back soon!)

This is already rather off-topic, and I can't possibly hope to go into as much detail as such matters deserve. However, if you're interested, we have a [standing chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134852) for discussing such topics that I would welcome you to join.

Comment: +1 vote for the perfect presentation of your facts

Comment: Yes, Got Questions is unashamedly Protestant, but even though I don't agree with everything they say, this link focuses on Got Questions articles about the year/month of the birth of Jesus: https://www.gotquestions.org/search.php?zoom_sort=0&zoom_query=Jesus+date+birth

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the fixation of Christ's day of birth, it was done by the Roman Catholic Church to commemorate his birth but it is **not** **accurate**. This is because the **season** of the time they claim that Christ was born is **winter** when there is snow outside but the season Jesus was born is in summer when there is no snow outside and shepherds can herd , no shepherd would herd outside during winter or **25th December**

Proof from scripture

*An angel appeared to a group of shepherds who were herding outside in the night and announced to them the good news*

Regarding your demand for a proof before you believe, proof is all around you. Scientists say the universe has an intelligent **designer** who placed everything in order. The primary proof is the **existence of life on planet earth**, other stars like our sun exist have planets around them and we have planets that are exactly the **suitable distance** from their **central stars for life to exist but they don't**

That is more than enough proof that it is **God** who **authorizes life to exist and not some cosmic law**

Comment: It's not exactly accurate to say it "was done by the Roman Catholic Church" and point to the Latin Rite of the Catholic Church like it's a denomination with some crazy idea.  This was clearly the date chosen and celebrated by all Christendom before someone got it in their mind to be skeptical.   Nobody claims that there was snow in Bethlehem,  and Jimmy Akin's got a pretty good reputation of the sheep argument https://jimmyakin.com/2014/11/do-sheep-prove-that-jesus-wasnt-born-on-december-25th.html

Comment: This doesn't cover the reason why Dec 25th was chosen, and just makes the Catholic Church look like a bunch of idiots. December 25th was chosen for the celebration of the nativity of our Lord because it is 9 months after March 25th, the feast of the annunciation. March 25th was chosen for the feast of the Annunciation because it was the date of Christ's crucifixion, and to an ancient mind, His life beginning and ending on the same day is indicative of perfection. Some people may actually believe the Annunciation had to happen on Mar 25, but neither the Bible nor the Church says it must have.

Answer (score 1):

**Why was Christ's birthday changed?**

The idea of making December 25 as Christ's birthday has it origins in the 2nd century. It liturgical celebration is known in the 4th century.

Christ’s date of birth was never changed. The Scriptures say neither what day Jesus was born on, nor what exactly the star was. Any dates people are suggesting are only theories at best. If you want to consider Dec 25 a fictional date, then you are free to do so! The true date of Jesus's birth is not important to Christianity. Many Christians simply desire to honour December 25th as the date of Jesus’ Nativity.

December can be very cold in Palestine in Christ’s day, but this posses no real reason to believe that Jesus was not born in winter.  Nobody has ever claimed that there was snow in Bethlehem in those days either.

Jimmy Akin's got a pretty good argument against those who think it would be to cold for shepherds to have their flocks out on December 25th.

> Sheep definitely were pastured in the vicinity of Bethlehem. Luke is correct about that. In fact, they are pastured there today.
>
> There are even two fields (one Catholic, one Greek Orthodox) that are known as the “Shepherds’ Field,” where pilgrims go to commemorate the events that Luke records. Both have shrines today.
>
> Neither can be established as the site Luke mentions. (Indeed, the site may have been at another nearby location entirely.)
>
> Now about the argument that it was too cold to be grazing sheep on December 25th. . . .
>
> Anybody want to say it was too cold for that sheep to withstand the rigors of a December night in the vicinity of Jerusalem, where the average nightly low for such nights (today) is 43 degrees Fahrenheit?
>
> Of course, average temperature changes over times, but the first century was well after the close of the last Ice Age.
>
> So maybe we want to be a little careful about declaring it “too cold” to keep sheep outdoors in the Jerusalem-Bethlehem area without, y’know, actually checking the facts.
>
> Speaking of which . . .
>
> Let’s Check the Facts!
>
> Whether or not Jesus was born on December 25th, the claim that sheep were not being grazed at this time of year is false. In fact, sheep are still grazed there at this time of year.
>
> - [Do sheep prove that Jesus wasn’t born on December 25th?](https://jimmyakin.com/2014/11/do-sheep-prove-that-jesus-wasnt-born-on-december-25th.html)

Strictly speaking there is no ambiguity in Scriptures on the subject matter of keeping or celebrating Jesus’ birthday. It simply is not mentioned in Scriptures. Some traditions chose to do so; while others chose not to do so. If I may be condemned for celebrating Christmas, so be it. I am not Ebenezer Scrooge and I do not humbug this subject matter as Ebenezer Scrooge would.

Yes, the Scriptures do not say anything about celebrating the Birth of Christ as we commonly say as Christmas, but the the Sacred Scriptures do not directly forbid it either.

Tertullian held that Christ’s conception and death were on March 25th, exactly nine months prior to December 25th.

> But where did he get this idea from, that the crucifixion was on the 8th day before the kalends of April, March 25?
>
> There is a lunar calendar on the statue of Hippolytus in the Vatican Library. Apparently a note within this indicates the “Passion of Christ” was on Friday March 25.
>
> Tertullian, Adversus Judaeos 8:18:
>
> *Quae passio Christi [huius exterminium] intra tempora LXX ebdomadarum perfecta est sub Tiberio Caesare, consulibus Rubellio Gemino et Rufio Gemino mense Martio temporibus paschae, die octavo Kalendarum Aprilium, die primo azymorum quo agnum occiderunt ad vesperam, sicut a Moyse fuerat praeceptum.*
>
> And the suffering of this “extermination” was perfected within the times of the lxx hebdomads, under Tiberius Caesar, in the consulate of Rubellius Geminus and Fufius Geminus, in the month of March, at the times of the passover, on the eighth day before the calends of April, on the first day of unleavened bread, on which they slew the lamb at even, just as had been enjoined by Moses. - [March 25 – the date of the annunciation, the crucifixion, and the origin of December 25 as the date of Christmas?](https://www.roger-pearse.com/weblog/2021/03/25/march-25-the-date-of-the-annunciation-the-crucifixion-and-the-origin-of-december-25-as-the-date-of-christmas/)

As decided Christians, we can not all be in accord with this idea of celebrating the Birth of Jesus, in his incarnation and physically dwelt amongst men.

Yet, St. Paul himself admits, be it in a roundabout way, that some things may not be written down in Sacred Scriptures. I am not trying to be argumentative here. But rather point out that Catholics see things in a different light. As long as Christendom is divided there will be no unity in thought, tradition or beliefs to one degree or another.

> So then, brothers and sisters, stand firm and hold fast to the teachings we passed on to you, whether by word of mouth or by letter. - 2 Thessalonians 2:15

Hippolytus of Rome (A.D. 170-240) provides one of the earliest known references to the December 25 birth of Christ in his commentary on Daniel. According to St. John Chrysostom the [custom of celebrating the Solemnity of our Saviour’s Nativity](https://earlychurchtexts.com/public/john_chrysostom_homily_in_diem_natalem_domini_nostri_jesu_christi.htm) in his Homily for this Feast, that the Western Churches had, from the very commencement of Christianity, kept it on December 25th.

Comment: ...and even if March 25 is a correct date of *conception*, nine months is only an *average*; the chances that Christ was born *exactly* "nine months" (and what does that mean, anyway, given that different months are different lengths?) after conception are... poor. As an approximation, it'll do, but the point stands that we don't know the exact date.

Comment: @Matthew it is simply a traditional date with no obligations on other Christians to follow.

Answer (score 1):

> OP: Please I want to believe but I need solid proof that this isn't just something people hold onto and this stuff is real and not fake.

My take is that apparently the OP believes there was an historical figure Jesus Christ, as evidenced in the Bible, but really has an issue with the church/denomination.

Of all the potential questions about the veracity of the bible, why focus on the assumed day of Jesus' birth?

> Christmas was not among the earliest festivals of the Church. Irenaeus and Tertullian omit it from their lists of feasts; Origen, glancing perhaps at the discreditable imperial Natalitia, asserts (in Lev. Hom. viii in Migne, P.G., XII, 495) that in the Scriptures sinners alone, not saints, celebrate their birthday; Arnobius (VII, 32 in P.L., V, 1264) can still ridicule the "birthdays" of the gods. [NewAdvent Christmas](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03724b.htm)

So what might be one potential source?

> The well-known solar feast, however, of Natalis Invicti, celebrated on 25 December, has a strong claim on the responsibility for our December date. IBID

There is also the possible [Brumalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brumalia).

In contrast, we know the Old Testament tabernacle of Moses was a pattern (Exodus 25:9, 40, Hebrews 8:5).  As such, it might yield an alternative.

Christ, we know, fulfilled Passover (perfect sacrificial lamb), Feast of Unleavened Bread (ridding of sin), First Fruits (resurrection), and Pentecost (giving of Spirit), which are the Spring feasts.

What of His birthday?  It may be found in a Fall feast.

> And the Word was made flesh, and dwelt among us, (and we beheld his glory, the glory as of the only begotten of the Father,) full of grace and truth. John 1:14

The word translated "dwelt" is skenoo.  It means tabernacled.  God tabernacled with us.

> σκηνόω skēnóō, skay-no'-o; from G4636; to tent or encamp, i.e. (figuratively) to occupy (as a mansion) or (specially), to reside (as God did in the Tabernacle of old, a symbol of protection and communion):—dwell. [Strong's](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g4637/kjv/tr/0-1/)

That would have been in our September.

> OP: I have always had issues with the Bible and thought about God but my life is in shambles and everyone keeps telling me to just believe.

There is "blind faith".  There is also a knowing.  God isn't afraid of our questions.  Knock, ask, you will be answered.

Comment: **"Tertullian omit it from their lists of feasts"** True. But he holds the the conception of Jesus Christ was on March 25th. Nine months later is December 25.

Comment: Hmm, can you cite Tertullian's text in which he says that?

Comment: The Latin text is in my answer.

Comment: One may as well say Christ was conceived about the Summer solstice, count off 9 months, and come to Passover (passion).  IOW, Tertullian doesn't assert a 12/25 (Christmas) conception or birth that I see.

Comment: Reread Tertullian paper.  ".There are, (then,) made up cccxxx and vii years, v months: (whence are filled up lxii hebdomads and an half:  which make up ccccxxxvii years, vi months:) on the day of the birth of Christ. "  If Tertullian was using a 1/1 to 12/31 calendar, then this is confirmation he thought the birth of Christ was indeed in June (month 6).  Doesn't make it true necessarily, and I would stand by Christ's Fall birth at Tabernacles, but it certainly would not imply Tertullian thought 12/25 was Christ's date of birth.